# Multiple levels of quotes in C# for javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, escaping, special-characters

I have "custom control" project that constructs a string of javascript to plug into another application.  The application calls the "custom control" to determine certain behaviors.

The problem I'm having involves the need for multiple levels of quotes within my string containing javascript.  In the version below, I've tried escaping the inner quotes, but IE throws an error (Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101).  I have solved similar problems in the past by putting javascript in a separate js file and calling it from the plugin code.  In this case, however, I cannot get the application to "see" the js file.  How can I put the javascript into a string that I can pass?

The relevant code is:

```
class Class1 : Literal
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        var controlHtml = new StringBuilder();

        controlHtml.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        controlHtml.Append("$('#prodcon_error_msg').css('display', 'none');" +
                           "$('#prodcon_client_id_filterimg').click(function() {" +
                           "ShowFilterDialog('Client ID', 'clientId');" +
                           "});");
        controlHtml.Append("function ShowFilterDialog(criteriaName, filterTitle) {" +
                           "alert('show dialog code here for ' + criteriaName);" +
                           "var filterDialogDiv = document.createElement('DIV');");

        controlHtml.Append("filterDialogDiv.innerHTML = \"<div id='customaccountcriteriafilterdialog' class='dialogback'><div class='dialogheadingarea'>" +
                            "<span class='dialogtitle' style='float: left;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;\" + filterTitle + \" Lookup</span>" +
                            "<img class='dialogcloseimage' onmouseup=\"removeElement('customaccountcriteriafilterdialog');\" src='../../images/boxy.gif'/>" +
                            "</div><br/>Key word: <input type='text' id='criteriaFilterKeyword' /></div>");

        controlHtml.Append("filterDialogDiv.style.position = 'absolute';" +
                           "filterDialogDiv.style.left = '300px';" +
                           "filterDialogDiv.style.top = '85px';" +
                           "filterDialogDiv.style.Zindex = 4; " +
                           "document.body.appendChild(filterDialogDiv);" +
                           "}");

        this.Text = controlHtml.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note: The ending script tag is added by the calling application before appending.

Comment: Have you inspected the rendered HTML that the resultant HTML/JavaScript is correct? If not, what aspects _specifically_ are failing to output correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't have code like this.  That content should be in the markup file, or even a separate .js file, rather than in C# code.

Comment: Just for starters and i could be missing it but I don't see where you close your Script tag?

Comment: Side note: I think this is very good example of how not to write code - it mixes as many language as possible into one: C#, JavaScript, HTML, CSS; mixing different styles of manipulating HTML DOM; mixing JQuery and raw DOM element creation. Consider splitting your code into JavaScript/CSS/HTML parts - no need to triple-escape quotes...

Comment: Your setting of innerHTML looks wrong, in the 4th call to Append, you escape the double quote at the start of the <div> tag, but then there is no double quote escaped at the end. It looks like this would render as `filterDialogDiv.innerHTML = "<div ..>...</div>`, missing the trailing double quote and the `;` to end the statement.

Comment: also seeing as you are using stringbuilder. Whats with the concatenation?

Comment: Servy and Alexei, In a perfect world, I agree that things should not be done this way.  However, the world in which I am forced to write code is not perfect.  I have to work within my employer's guidelines and make things interface with very imperfect applications.  This is the real world.

Comment: An excellent question, Tony.  controlHtml had been a string.  I changed it to stringbuilder and replaced all the controlHtml += with controlHtml.Append, but hadn't completed the change when I posted.

Comment: mallan1121, Thank you.  You were correct about the trailing double quote and ;.  I corrected those, but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to put the whole code in a txt file and this txt file should be marked as an [embedded resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292). If some parts of the text should be formatted according to variable values, the solution is using string.Format to do so.

To load the txt file, simply use

```
try
   {
      var _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      var _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyTextFile.txt"));
var text = _textStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

// use the variable text for something...
   }
   catch
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
   }
```

I hope it helps. Best regards.